# Changing Automated Email for Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using the Approval Sharepoint - 2010

Staff are able to request Annual Leave and an email will be sent to myself so I can approve it.

My issue is that once I approve it or decline it they get a generic email that makes no real sense. All it tells them is that the task is complete but won't notify them that it has been rejected.

My problem is that we don't have access to Sharepoint Designer. We only have the out of the box Sharepoint and was wondering if there is any way for me to edit the automated email

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your options are limited if you don't even have SharePoint Designer, basically the only option I think you then have using the out-of-the-box workflows is to do the following;

1. (optionally) Disable the email sent as part of the approval workflow
2. Create one or more List based alerts based on the status of the approval column, ie an alert based on a view that shows items matching the filter "Approval Status" = "Approved".

However you'll probably find that the out-of-the-box view alert content is equally unhelpful, but at least it will contain everything, including something like a "Approval Comment" column on the list item.

HTH,

Comment: Thank you for this, with this am I able to set it up so it will send the email to the specific member of staff who requested the Annual Leave?

Comment: Yes if the requester is a field on the form then you could create an alert based on that field, ie define a view that includes filters by that field and the approval status - then set the alert to be sent when an item "enters" that view, ie when it satisfies the view filter criteria.

Comment: I don't fully understand but I will give it a go. Thank you

Comment: I've actually looked on google everywhere and people are saying it's not possible to disable the email sent